# Getting ActivityNotFoundException even though it should exist

Tags: android, android-intent

Yet another one of these, however none of the answers supplied on those posted helped.

I'm basicly just trying to open an Activity from another.
Error is as follows:

`E/AndroidRuntime(25932): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.softnux.android.lists/android.app.ListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ListsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ListActivity" ></activity>
</application>
```

My main activity:

```
package org.softnux.android.lists;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ListsActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lists);

        Button intentTestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.intentTestButton);

        intentTestButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent showListViewIntent = new Intent(ListsActivity.this,
                        ListActivity.class);
                startActivity(showListViewIntent);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

The activity I'm trying to open:

```
package org.softnux.android.lists;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ListActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `ListActivity` causing problem here:

```
Intent showListViewIntent = new Intent(ListsActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
startActivity(showListViewIntent);
```

because you have import

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
```

which imports the `ListActivity` provided by android framework.

### **Solution:**

Try to remove that import.

or the **recommended** way is to rename your `Activity` with name other than `ListActivity`